# TextView Center Vertical not working in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am having trouble with "Location" TextView not able to align "center_vertical" side-by-side with a LinearLayout that contains a spinner child inside. CustomSpinner is derived from class Spinner to handle custom onItemSelected event.

Attached is the XML code and Screenshots of expected result vs actual result.

Any help would be appreciated !

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCheckStockStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:text="Check Stock Status"
        android:textColor="@color/color_primary"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItemCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvCheckStockStatus"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:text="@string/sample_text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ivRemark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvItemCode"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivRemark"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/description"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivRemark"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvItemCode"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remark"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edDescription"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/location"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:allowUndo="false"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spLocationBlock" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spLocationBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/location"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edDescription"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="false">

        <widgets.CustomSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Expected Result**
[image: Expected Result]

**Actual Result**
[image: Actual Result]

Comment: **android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"** is used just in **LinearLayout**

Answer (score 1):

> It is better to use in `Relative Layout` `android:centerVertical="true"` and `alignParentRight="true"` instead of `android:gravity`.

Comment: Solved by removing the scroll view. Now everything works fine. Not sure why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

for *TextView*

Comment: Solved by removing the scroll view. Now everything works fine. Not sure why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

---

See in below code.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCheckStockStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:text="Check Stock Status"
            android:textColor="@color/color_primary"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvItemCode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCheckStockStatus"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:text="@string/sample_text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ivRemark"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvItemCode"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivRemark"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/description"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivRemark"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvItemCode"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remark"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edDescription"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/location"
            android:textColor="#555555"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:allowUndo="false"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spLocationBlock" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/spLocationBlock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/location"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/location"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edDescription"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false">

            <widgets.CustomSpinner
                android:id="@+id/spLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Solved by removing the scroll view. Now everything works fine. Not sure why. Thanks!